# Hasse diagrams with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to do the following in LaTeX with Ti*k*Z?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very primitive Ti*k*Z solution (still learning ;-)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[gray]  (0,0) -- (0,6cm);
  \draw[gray,dashed] (0cm,6cm) -- (0,7cm);

  \fill ( 0,0cm) circle[radius=1mm,black];
  \fill ( 0,3cm) circle[radius=1mm,black];
  \fill ( 0,6cm) circle[radius=1mm,black];
  \node   at (0.5cm,3cm)  {$\mathbb{R}$} ;
  \node   at (0.5cm,6cm)  {$\mathbb{C}$} ;
  \node   at (0.5cm,0cm)  {$\mathbb{Q}$} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit -- some improvement**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0); 
  \coordinate (B) at (0,3cm);
  \coordinate (C) at (0,6cm);
  \coordinate (D) at (0,7cm);
  \draw[gray,line width=1.5pt]  (A) -- (C);
  \draw[gray,dashed,line width=1.5pt] (C) -- (0,7cm);
  \fill (A) circle[radius=1mm,black];
  \fill (B) circle[radius=1mm,black];
  \fill (C) circle[radius=1mm,black];
  \node [xshift=0.5cm]  at (A)  {$\mathbb{Q}$} ;
  \node [xshift=0.5cm]  at (B)  {$\mathbb{R}$} ;
  \node [xshift=0.5cm]  at (C)  {$\mathbb{C}$} ;
  \node [xshift=0.5cm]  at (D)  {?};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I love your first solution because of his semplicity. Thank you and happy new year! Another question. If I want change the colour of the circle how to do that? For instance, if I put red instead of black nothing happens. Thank you!

Comment: How about (for the first one): `\foreach \x/\label in {%
        0/$\mathbb{Q}$,
        3/$\mathbb{C}$,
        6/$\mathbb{R}$,
        7/?
    }{
    \ifnum\x<7
        \node[fill=black, circle, inner sep=0, minimum size=2mm, label=0:\label] at (0,\x) {};
    \else
        \node[inner sep=0, minimum size=2mm, label=0:\label] at (0,\x) {};
    \fi
}` :P Even shorter!

Answer (score 7):

Like this?

[image: output]

It is easy:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,chains}

    \usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 11mm,
  start chain = going above,
   set/.style = {shape=circle, fill= red,% fill determine color of fill
                 inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0pt,
                 label=right:$\mathbb{#1}$,
                 join= by -, on chain,
                 node contents={}}
                      ]
\node (q) [set=Q];
\node (r) [set=R];
\node (c) [set=C];
\draw (c) -- +(0,0.5);
\draw[dashed] ($(c)+(0,0.5)$) -- + (0,0.7) node[right] {?};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For nodes `N` positioning is used Ti*k*Z library `chains`, position of node with `?` is used library `calc`. Text to nodes is added as labels with exception of nodes with `?`.

**Edit:** Benefits of the above code is that the node style is determined in a single place;, also the placement is determined centrally by `node distance`. So any changes to the picture is easy to implement. For example, now I change the color of nodes and make them a bit smaller.

Probably this approach seems to be less intuitive or complicated for beginners. However, after drawing for example fifty similar pictures, the shown approach will show it's advantage. `:-)`

Comment: @AndreaLeo, thank you for your wishes. The same to you, and many happy (La)TeX-ing!

Comment: As a matter of fact I am a beginner :) Thank you! your edit is very useful to me! Again, have a nice 2016!

Answer (score 5):

Une solution assez simple (tu aurais pu essayer!)

A simple solution (you could have a try!)

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}                       
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}                 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{amssymb }

\usepackage{tikz} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}


\node[circle,fill,inner sep=0,minimum size=2mm,label={right:$\mathbb Q$}](Q) at (0,0){};
\node[circle,fill,inner sep=0,minimum size=2mm,label={right:$\mathbb R$}](R) at (0,2){};
\node[circle,fill,inner sep=0,minimum size=2mm,label={right:$\mathbb C$}](C) at (0,4){};

\draw[thick,blue] (Q) --(R)-- (C);
\draw[thick,dashed,blue] (C)--++(0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

A one-line solution for conciseness:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path [draw, fill, every node/.style={right}] circle (1pt) node {$\mathbb{Q}$} -- ++(0,1) circle (1pt) node {$\mathbb{R}$} -- ++(0,1) circle (1pt) node {$\mathbb{C}$} -- ++(0,.25) edge [dashed] node [pos=1] {$?$} ++(0,.75) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: one-line solution]

If the line should be grey but the circles black, then it is probably easier to use two lines:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [draw=gray, every node/.style={right}] (0,0) node {$\mathbb{Q}$} -- ++(0,1)  node {$\mathbb{R}$} -- ++(0,1) node {$\mathbb{C}$} -- ++(0,.25) edge [dashed] node [pos=1] {$?$} ++(0,.75) ;
  \path [fill, draw] circle (1pt)  ++(0,1) circle (1pt)  ++(0,1) circle (1pt) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: two-liner]

Answer (score 4):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mlist}

\newmset\setQ{Q}
\newcommand*\set[2]{\uput[0](0.05,#1){$#2$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0.45,6)
  \psline[linecolor = gray](0.05,0.1)(0.05,4.8)
  \psline[linecolor = gray, linestyle = dashed](0.05,4.8)(0.05,5.9)
  \psdots[dotsize = 3pt 2](0.05,0.15)(0.05,2.075)(0.05,4)
  \uput[0](0.05,5.9){$?$}
  \set{4}{\setC}
  \set{2.075}{\setR}
  \set{0.15}{\setQ}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]